# webpack next.js TypeError: The "original" argument must be of type Function

Tags: webpack, next.js, webpack-dev-server

When I run npm run dev, I get the following error:
If there is someone who understands, please teach me

// error contents

TypeError: The "original" argument must be of type Function

./node_modules/node-libs-browser/node_modules/util/util.js:602
  599 | 
  600 | exports.promisify = function promisify(original) {
  601 |   if (typeof original !== 'function')

> 602 |     throw new TypeError('The "original" argument must be of type Function');
>     603 | 
>     604 |   if (kCustomPromisifiedSymbol && original[kCustomPromisifiedSymbol]) {
>     605 |     var fn = original[kCustomPromisifiedSymbol];

```
// next.config.js
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
module.exports = withSass({
  /* config options here */
});

module.exports = {
  webpack: config => {
   config.node = {
     fs: 'empty',
     child_process: 'empty',
     net: 'empty',
     dns: 'empty',
     tls: 'empty',
   };
   return config;
  },
};


// packege.json

    > "dependencies": {
    >     "@types/react-intl": "^3.0.0",
    >     "@types/react-lottie": "^1.2.3",
    >     "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
    >     "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    >     "googleapis": "^49.0.0",
    >     "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.0.0",
    >     "next": "^9.2.1",
    >     "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    >     "react": "^16.12.0",
    >     "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    >     "react-intl": "^3.12.0",
    >     "react-lottie": "^1.2.3"   },   "devDependencies": {
    >     "@types/node": "^13.7.0",
    >     "@types/react": "^16.9.19",
    >     "typescript": "^3.7.5"   }
```